# Il bordo saldato di una confezione

Tags: word-choice

Il bordo saldato di una confezione in carta o in foglio di plastica (esempi: un gelato Algida, le patatine Pai, i biscotti Misura Yogurt) può essere fatto cosí

```
|\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/|
|                                  |
```

Ora, se dicessi che il bordo è seghettato probabilmente mi farei capire, ma mi chiedo e vi chiedo se esiste un'altra *specifica* parola per descriverlo.

Answer (score 4):

Non vedo grandi alternative, *seghettato* è un termine comune che tutti dovrebbero capire, ed è piuttosto specifico.

Certo, alternative ci possono essere, ma mi sembrano peggio, se lo scopo è anche farsi capire.

Ad esempio, il dizionario Treccani propone *dentellato*, ottimo, grazioso termine che ricorda foglie e merletti, anch'esso piuttosto comune, ma che suona leggermente più 'aulico' di *seghettato*:

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/seghettato_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/

Altri sinonimi sono proposti nei link sotto, come ad esempio:

*dentato* o *con orlo a dentelli* (non cambia niente ripetto a *dentellato*, solo più brutto), *frastagliato* (troppo generico, difficilmente lo si direbbe del bordo di una confezione di biscotti), *modanato* (suonerebbe ridicolo, si dice dei mobili o dei fregi, e pochi sanno che vuol dire), *merlato* (si dice di costruzioni, ad esempio: *torre merlata*, *muro merlato*).

https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Sinonimi/D/dentellato.html

https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/seghettato

Se uno vuole un modo di dire più quotidiano potrebbe dire *a zig zag*, ma de gustibus, non vedo il vantaggio, visto che *seghettato* è italiano comune e più preciso.

Certo  *a zig zag*  forse sarebbe comprensibile più facilmente per uno straniero, ma per un italiano non cambia niente.

Comment: A me invece dentellato piace, credo si usi tanto in botanica quanto in filatelia. La tua risposta (+1) è però alquanto dismissiva riguardo a questa mia preferenza, e quindi per me inaccettabile nella sua forma attuale.

Comment: Non sto dismettendo niente, ho detto anche io che *dentellato* mi piace, ma è un po' meno quotidiano (se lo scopo è anche farsi capire da tutti), *seghettato* è quello che più facilmente direbbe chiunque nel discorso di tutti i giorni,  riferito a quegli oggetti, tutto qui: se vado in un negozio non mi aspetto che un cliente o il negoziante  dica *dentellato* del pacco di biscotti,   ma *seghettato* caso mai sì.  Ma sono sfumature. Ho  esposto delle caratteristiche dei vari termini, mica ti sto dicendo quale usare, non sto giudicando nessuna preferenza. Vedi tu.

Comment: Vedo *dentellato* meno facilmente associato (nell'uso, mica è un mio giudizio sulla parola),  a oggetti 'prosaici' come il pacco di patatine, più a oggetti più 'alti' come merletti, foglie e francobolli, ma ripeto, sono sfumature e cose soggettive, e molto dipende dal contesto, poi ognuno è libero di crearsi un proprio stile linguistico.